# jQuery -> XML -> Array - dynamically created buttons and links

Tags: jquery, arrays, button, dynamic-data, dynamic-links

Is or is not simple, but need your help with this:

I need to dynamically create buttons and  links in jQuery.
Data loaded from XML is put in an array and now:

You might click on one of the buttons "category" "users" etc...
it launches a function that should make a button for each of the categories
f.ex.:
lets make a function that will be launched by those buttons:
it will search XML for  with categoryID attr that contains txt with "something..." and will add it to #tester:

```
function clickedCat(cat){
      alert("test btn" + cat); // to check if function started
      // here just some script search 'cat' in XML etc...
    })
}
```

now the function has to be triggered by the dynamically created buttons f.ex.:

```
function showCatName(){
    $("#categories").html(" ");
    for(i=0;i<catArr.length;i++){
    qw = catIDArr[i];
    $("<div id='showCatName"+qw+"'></div>").html("<input id='showCatName"+qw+"' type='button' title='showCatName"+qw+"' value='showCatName"+qw+"' />")
                        .click(function(event){clickedCat(qw)}).appendTo("#categories");
    }
}
```

but the button created here has the same value for all of them - last qw that was loaded...

Q:  How to make it remember the qw value - different for each btn ?
so btn[0] launches qw[0], btn[1] launches qw[1] etc...

Second thing -same issue but i need to input that into html link :

```
function showCatName2(){
    $("#categories").html(" ");
    for(i=0;i<catArr.length;i++){
    qw2 = catIDArr[i];
    $("<div id='showCatName"+qw2+"'></div>")
    .html("<a href='#' onclick:clickedCat("+qw2+")> Test btn"+qw2+"</a>")
    .appendTo("#categories2");
    }
}
```

onclick doesn't seem to work at all ...

Q1:   How to make it work so it will dynamically create buttons that launch a function with different value ?

Q2: like above but istead of buttons i need to put it in  link

Thank for help in advance,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You're having a closure problem with `showCatName()`. When you say this:

```
function(event){ clickedCat(qw) }
```

You're binding a reference to `qw` to the function but this **does not evaluate** `qw`. The `qw` variable is evaluated when the click handler is triggered and the value of `qw` will be what it had when the loop finished; all the click handlers will have the same `qw` value because, well, they all share the exact same variable. The usual solution to this is to force `qw` to be evaluated when building the click handler:

```
function make_click(qw) {
    return function() { clickedCat(qw); };
}
// ...
function showCatName(){
    $("#categories").html(" ");
    for(i=0;i<catArr.length;i++) {
        qw = catIDArr[i];
        $("<div id='showCatName"+qw+"'></div>")
            .html("<input id='showCatName"+qw+"' type='button' title='showCatName"+qw+"' value='showCatName"+qw+"' />")
            .click(make_click(qw))
            .appendTo("#categories");
    }
}
```

You could use an immediately executing inlined function in place of `make_click()` but the above is probably clearer if you're having trouble with closures.

Your second one does not work because `onclick:clickedCat` doesn't mean anything in HTML. Perhaps you meant `onclick=clickedCat`. You'll probably run into quoting problems with `qw2` with this approach.